# Including JavaScript libraries to IntelliJ IDEA's autocomplete

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

How I can include my own JavaScript library to IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 or 11? I want to tell IDEA that she must use autocomplete with my library's objects. Sometimes it works automaticaly, but sometimes is not — IDEA didn't add some files content to autocomplete's list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the blog post and related help section:

- [JavaScript Libraries in Intellij IDEA 10](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/11/javascript-libraries-in-intellij-idea-10/)
- [Configuring JavaScript Libraries](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html)