# Sencha Touch IDE or Editor

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Is there any Sencha Touch 2 IDE or Editor? I know about Sencha Architect 2. But it is too costly. If anyone using Sencha Touch IDE, so we can give only CTRL+SPACE, and it will give me the all methods?

Comment: I have created a detailed tutorial with pictures for this specific reason, Please let me know what do you think and how it worked out :) http://www.shereef.net/2012/12/11/sencha-touch-2-autocomplete-example-in-aptana-studio/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Aptana (free) adding a custom autocompletion library for Ext.js / Sencha.
Works quite well with Sencha Touch 1 (I didn't find it yet for ST2).

1. Into Aptana Studio go to Help -> Install New Software
2. Click "Add" to add a repository

   - Name: Spket IDE
   - Location: http://www.spket.com/update/
3. In "Work with:" list select the item u just added
   A list will appear wit 3 repositoryes for Spket IDE. (Spket IDE, Spket Text Editor and Xerces for Spket IDE)
   Install all of them
4. Download http://www.agpad.com/downloads/com.spket.js_1.6.18.jar
5. Replace the existing file located in "C:\Program Files\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio 3\plugins" or where did you installed Aptana (in "plugins" folder)
   You must install this because Spket only supports format "jsb1" and "jsb2". With this fix it will support "jsb3" (wich Sencha Touch use it).
6. In Aptana Studio go to Windows -> Preferences -> Spket -> Javascript Profiles

   - Click "New" and write "SenchaTouch"
   - Select "SenchaTouch" and click "Add Library" and select "ExtJs" from the list displayed
   - Select "ExtJs" and click "Add File"
     Locate youre "sencha-touch.jsb3" wich is containted in the zip file downloaded from sencha.com. (make sure all the files from that archive are located in the same folder)
     ....and click "Open"
   - Select "SenchaTouch" again and click "Default" button
   - Click "OK"

Now open a ".js" script of a sencha touch project and check it out.

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how can i create a sencha project and work on that? And is it possible to run the project which is for mobile.? Like in sencha Architect, we can see the preview of the layout.

Comment: This no longer works on version 2, i tested it over and over again.

Comment: I never tested it back on ST2, don't know if spket upgraded the autocomplete plugin... :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an IDE for Sencha Touch as such. There's no IDE that can give you CTRL+Space functionality.

Use [senchafiddle.com](http://www.senchafiddle.com/) instead ...

Comment: But can i download this sencha fiddle? will it work like a editor?

Comment: I checked the below links, but really puzzled.                             http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179932-Best-IDE-to-work-with-sencha-touch-2.X&highlight=Editor

Comment: Nope, you can't download this senchafiddle. It's not a software. Btw, you can run your code in *MVC* format and can even download it in the same form in the .zip file :)

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ you can add the Sencha Touch libraries and you will get some completion.  It's not perfect but it definitely helps.  You can try it free for 30 days.

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/04/smarter-javascript-completion-in-intellij-idea-111/

This related question has additional information:

[Including JavaScript libraries to IntelliJ IDEA's autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576588/including-javascript-libraries-to-intellij-ideas-autocomplete)

Comment: How to get that sencha touch plugins for Intellij-idea

Comment: You download the ST2 libraries from  (http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/) Sencha and follow CrazyCoder's first link (http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/11/javascript-libraries-in-intellij-idea-10/) to add the Javascript libraries to your project.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a Sencha Touch plugin for intelliJ, which colors tabs, adds icons to help to differ the MVC files and add code templates to empty MVC files.
(I uploaded images [here](http://www.m-gd.com/sencha-workflow-intellij-plugin-senchatouchmvcolors/))

Further since intellij 12 code completion is really great even without adding ST libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using eclipse with aptana 3 and spket plugins. You can configure spket to use auto complete feature to work with sencha touch 2.3.1. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24672108/3824335).

Answer (score 0):

Sencha’s recently launched JetBrains plugin is an Integrated Development Environment tool that creates a confluence between Sencha Frameworks and JetBrains software. This integration comes in the form of code completion, inspection, and suggestion, while seamlessly cooperating with native JetBrains behavior.

Cheapest license available is for WebStorm infact free for students and other special categories.

Sencha experts will love the the ease with which changes are refactored and how simple it is to trace code to the source.

Sencha beginners will benefit as the JetBrains plugin provides completion suggestions while encouraging best-practice code structure and syntax.

What more it is available for development of both Touch as well as ExtJS.
For more details follow [Sencha link](http://docs.sencha.com/tools/ide_plugins/jetbrains_ide_plugin.html)