# Code completion - Sencha + Aptana Studio 3

Tags: autocomplete, aptana, sencha-touch-2.3

I am working on Aptana Studio 3 and have downloaded Sencha as below link would advice:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/first_app

I.e. downloaded Sencha (and XAMPP, installed the unzipped sencha files into a folder called touch inside xampp/htdocs).
Localhost/touch/examples show up fine - so it is definitely working

Have also installed Sencha cmd. This installs sencha cmd line tool version 4.0.x - and I am able to create a folder NewApp with skeletal sencha project using

```
sencha generate app NewApp NewApp
```

The content is created inside xampp/htdocs/touch/NewApp folder

Strangely, the tutorial in the link above says to use the command:
    sencha -sdk /path/to/touch generate app MyApp
However, I have not been instructed to install the SDK (I tried doing this, but the SDK installed has the sencha cmd line tool version 2.x.x - so I have uninstalled it

I am importing this NewApp folder in Aptana Studio and trying to work with this. How do I get code completion working?

I tried following these instructions : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?112540-Aptana-Code-Assist-for-Sencha-Touch

> 6 . In Aptana Studio go to Windows -> Preferences -> Spket -> Javascript Profiles
>   - Click "New" and write "SenchaTouch"
>   - Select "SenchaTouch" and click "Add Library" and select "ExtJs" from the list displayed
>   - Select "ExtJs" and click "Add File" Locate youre "sencha-touch.jsb3" wich is containted in the zip file downloaded from sencha.com. (make
>   sure all the files from that archive are located in the same folder)
>   ....and click "Open"

However, I simply do not have a .jsb3 file in the zip file i downloaded from for installing Sencha 2.3

Answer (score 1):

There is no more .jsb3 files for sencha touch library since 2.2.1. See this _http://tol8.blogspot.de/2013/02/sencha-ext-js-support-in-eclipse-tested.html.

Use spket plugin to make auto complite function work on eclipse and sencha touch 2.3.x. You can use .js (sencha-touch-all.js) file from sencha touch library working instead of .jsb3 file. I found this [blog](http://www.programering.com/a/MTN0ATMwATc.html) and tried it with sencha touch 2.3.1 update. To get setter and getter function work check [spket forum](http://forums.spket.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1866&start=75#p6825).

Comment: this answer is correct, use sencha-touch-all.js instead of sencha-touch.jsb3